# save array as binary file

Tags: php, arrays

How would I save an array to a binary file and then read that binary file back to an array in php?

This is where I am so far, but it doesn't work:

```
$arr = array("key1"=>"val1","key2"=>"val2","key3"=>"val3");

//save file
$file_w = fopen('binint', 'w+');
$bin_str = pack('i', $arr);
fwrite($file_w, $bin_str);
fclose($file_w);

//load file
$filename = "file.bin";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
$newarr = unpack('i*', $contents);

print_r($newarr);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's wrong with serialize() or json_encode()?

Comment: why a binary file? as mentioned earlier, saving JSON is probably the best way to go...

Comment: as useful as a json file is, i believe bin files take up less space in the hard drive